# Flying to India - visa and country closure

Tags: visas, india, standard-visitor-visas, uk-citizens, tourism

I intend to travel to India on 20th July. My current visa runs out on the 7th July so I'd obviously need to apply for a new one. Can I do that before my current one expires?

Comment: which city do u plan to travel to?

Comment: The country is slowly reopening after the lock down. I found this article where the Uttarakhand state government has lifted restrictions https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/travel/travel-news/uttarakhand-reopens-for-all-travel-restrictions-lifted/as76772254.cms and also this link discussing the resumption of international flights https://www.financialexpress.com/lifestyle/travel-tourism/international-flights-like-lufthansa-emirates-and-qatar-airways-start-operations-india-to-start-next-month/2012216/

Answer (score 9):

You have bigger problems. Right now only specific flights charted by Air India is operating to India and very limited other charted flights. On that itself, only citizens of India are allowed it according to priority, after approval from respective embassies.

Your current visa is most probably suspended or cancelled and you have to apply for a fresh visa, which is really unlikely to be approved.

Details on eVISA - https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html

Comment: Thank you for your much valued answer. Yes, I'm fully aware of current travel restrictions and am watching daily anticipating a change. Up until today the Indian immigration bureau website has had no option to even apply for a visa however that is no longer the case and it appears to be open for applications. Maybe I'm just being too hopeful right now!!

Comment: @Loucobby Since you are willing to take that risk, you can apply for eVisa. Your previous visa doesn't matter as, the notifications made previously cancelled all existing visas of those persons who didn't enter yet.